# Upgrading Tor on Ubuntu as a relay operator

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting

I have just come across an article stating that Tor has a new version released 0.3.0.6. and is stable.

1st question how do I find out what version of Tor I am running.

2nd question how do I update Tor to new version, will this mean shutting my new relay down?

Comment: Than you to both Jens and Peter, very helpful, making notes as I get more info on how things work, so I shouldn't be asking the same questions twice.

Comment: My TOR version is 0.2.9.10

Comment: I have tried looking in the etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ neither have that line of text (deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.0.x-xenial main)in it and the list.d/ only has one document in it google-chrome.list

Comment: Peter, I have checked my torrc file and I had added the lines

Comment: eb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jessie main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jessie main

Comment: so will this update TOR as and when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I find out what version of Tor I am running?

```
dpkg -l tor
```

> question how do I update Tor to a new version?

Update all packages installed:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Update Tor only:

```
apt-get install tor
```

If your using the Tor version coming with Ubuntu you may not receive the 3.0.6 update, many distributions use older version (which are still supported and receive security updates). If you want the newest version have a look at [this guide](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en).

> will this mean shutting my new relay down?

```
Yes, your relay will be offline for about a minute.
```

Comment: Note that `apt update && apt upgrade` will automatically restart tor for you if there was a newer version of tor. No need to `systemctl restart tor`. At least that's how it was for me.

Answer (score 0):

> 1st question how do I find out what version of Tor I am running.

There are several possibilities:

1. `tor --version` on the command line issues the version number: `Tor version 0.2.9.10 (git-e28303bcf90b842d).`
2. `apt-cache policy tor` is a system command and leads to several lines of output. The important line is `Installed: 0.2.9.10-1`.
3. When Tor starts it writes some information to the log: `grep "opening new log" /var/log/tor/notices.log` outputs the line `May 14 07:35:05.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.10 (git-e28303bcf90b842d) opening new log file.`

> 2nd question how do I update Tor to new version, will this mean shutting my new relay down?

You should first have a look at your `sources.list`. This is either in `etc/apt/sources.list` or a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Depending on the Ubuntu version you have there is a line like `deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.0.x-xenial main`. If the version string in the middle is different from `0.3.0` you should change that to `0.3.0`. Then run `aptt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. Ubuntu will automatically restart your relay which means that it is offline during the upgrade.